# How to correctly use withIndex with takeUntil ,forEachWhile, with RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java2, iterable, takeuntil

In my expression, even `takeUntil` is true/false, subscribe method is emitting all the list items, which should stop once `takeUntil` is true right?

```java
Observable.fromIterable(countryResponseList.withIndex())
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .takeUntil((index,item) -> item.getId() == currentCountryCodeId)
  .subscribe((index,item) -> run{
     Log.d("items and index", " ${item} and ${index}")
  })
```

What i need is to get the current index, when the expressions match(  item.getId() == currentCountryCodeId) each other and the RxJava expression should stop continuing. I don't know how to do that, any help appreciated. I also found `forEachWhile`, will that suit this situation?

Comment: `takeUntil` takes only one parameter, how you can pass index & item ? are you sure that this code compile ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you want to stop iterating `countryResponseList.withIndex()`. If so, the upstream should be run on the same thread with `takeUntil`.

Hope underlying is what you want. If not, how about describe more in detail?

```
Observable.fromIterable(countryResponseList.withIndex())
  .takeUntil((index,item) -> item.getId() == currentCountryCodeId)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .subscribe((index,item) -> run{
     Log.d("items and index", " ${item} and ${index}")
  })
```